# linq get all rows then loop to get the value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I think this may be a problem related to syntax. What I want is to query and get all my records from the database and then to use `foreach` to iterate through the records.

The problem here is that if I query in linq like this:

**query:**

```
var balance = db.UserBalance.Where(d => d.ApplicationUserId == userId);
```

it never recognizes the properties from the balance to construct something like this:

**foreach loop**

```
foreach(var i in saldo)
{
    if(balance.value < 0)
    {
        earnings += balance.value;
    }
    else
    {
        expenses -= saldo.value;
    }
}
```

If someone can give me a tip I would appreciate

PS: Sorry for my bad English

Comment: It's not really clear what you are doing and asking. `balance` is an enumeration (or a query), but you use it as a single value...what is `saldo`? Maybe you wanted to do `var balance = db.UserBalance.Where(d => d.ApplicationUserId == userId).FirstOrDefault();` to get the user and not an enumeration containing that user

Comment: already did, it still dont recognize the propoerty :S

Comment: You'll have performance problems if you'll count it on the application-side rather than database side. Read about .Sum() method of Linq to calculate that balance in DB.

Comment: i want to get all the records where the user is the same that is logged in and then witht he foreach loop iterate trough all the rows and get the column value

Comment: .Sum dont work, because i want to sum some records and sub another records, i just want to paste in my view some statistic dates related to earnings and expenses and thats why i need to loop the value to see if it is < 0, > 0

Comment: Could you please tell us, what Kind of Object "saldo" is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just guessing as you didn't show your tables etc., but you might want this:

```
float earnings = 0;
float expenses = 0;
foreach (var balance in db.UserBalance.Where(d => d.ApplicationUserId == userId))
{
    if(balance.value < 0)
        earnings += balance.value;
    else
        expenses -= balance.value;
}
```

The query returns an enumeration of `UserBalance`s for the given user, which is what you actually want to iterate through.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting out a list of balances ("All the records WHERE x is true"), but from your code it appears that you are expecting a unique record.

You can use [Single](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155325(v=vs.100).aspx) for this.

```
var balance = db.UserBalance.Single(d => d.ApplicationUserId == userId);
```

Note that if the record is not guaranteed to exist, use SingleOrDefault and perform a null check on balance.

```
var balance = db.UserBalance.SingleOrDefault(d => d.ApplicationUserId == userId);
if (balance == null) {
    // No balance was found.
    return;
}
```

Comment: i want to get all the records, where the userId == d.ApplicationUserId